# Action Bar doesn't appear on galaxy S3

Tags: android, android-actionbar, galaxy

I followed the [android developers](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/index.html) training and 
wrote application that should have action bar.

I added two items to the Action Bar:

- the first has icon and android:showAsAction="IfRoom"
- the second, has only string and android:showAsAction="Never".

main_menu_actions.xml:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:context="com.shaniandroid.myfirstapp.MainActivity" >

<!-- Search, should appear as action button -->
<item android:id="@+id/action_search"
      android:icon="@drawable/search_icon"
      android:title="@string/action_search"
      android:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
<!-- Settings, should always be in the overflow -->
<item android:id="@+id/action_settings"
      android:title="@string/action_settings"
      android:showAsAction="never" />
```

However the Action Bar is not displayed!

The items are only displayed when the menu button
is pressed.

I read in earlier answers that the "overflow" button doesn't appear 
on 4.3 if a hardware menu button is present - and that is OK for the second item.

But what about the first item - shouldn't it appear with its icon on top of screen?

Notice: I run the app on galaxy S3 4.3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using AppCompat then you should use `app` namespace for `showAsAction` which you have declared. Your main_menu_actions.xml should then look like this:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:context="com.shaniandroid.myfirstapp.MainActivity" >

<!-- Search, should appear as action button -->
<item android:id="@+id/action_search"
      android:icon="@drawable/search_icon"
      android:title="@string/action_search"
      app:showAsAction="ifRoom" /> <!--here-->
<!-- Settings, should always be in the overflow -->
<item android:id="@+id/action_settings"
      android:title="@string/action_settings"
      app:showAsAction="never" /> <!--and here-->
```

Comment: Oh thank u, didn't realize that. i will check this.  Q:what is better to do - use AppCompat or not? i don't see much reason to suppport versions lower than 4.x.

Comment: @shani If you don't want to support pre ICS devices then use native ActionBar.

Comment: Does "use native Action Bar" mean not using AppCompat at all?

Comment: AppCompat is compatibility library that allows you to add ActionBar on Android versions prior to ICS (actually Honeycomb). So if your target is ICS or later then you don't need AppCompat at all.